# Stuck on comparing strings

Tags: java

I have to creat an application that prompts the user for his or her name, including title. The application should display "Hello,sir" if the string stars with *Mr.*, "Hello,ma'am" if the string starts with *Ms.,Mrs., or Miss*, and "Hello,*name*" otherwise where *name* is the user's name.

This is what I have so far, the application chokes when the user types in Mrs, because it finds the *Mr* s first, and I'm having trouble figuring out what I could do to get it to work. Let me know, thank you all beforehand for your answers! Beginner Java so keep it simple please!

```
package chapter6java;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class FormalGreeting {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String name, mr = "Mr", mrs = "Mrs", ms = "Ms", miss = "Miss";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your name including title (ie. Mr, Mrs): ");
        name = input.nextLine();

        if (name.startsWith(mr)) {
            System.out.println("Hello,sir");
        } else if (name.startsWith(mrs)) {
            System.out.println("Hello,ma'am");
        } else if (name.startsWith(ms)) {
            System.out.println("Hello,ma'am");
        } else if (name.startsWith(miss)) {
            System.out.println("Hello,ma'am");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hello," +name);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the order of your comparisons: check for "Mrs" before you check for "Mr".

Answer (score 1):

```
String.split("\\.");
```

If your string has a dot, it will be splitted. Then you can compare to "Mrs" and "Mr."

Or you can split with a space (and remove the dot of the end of string if there is one)

Answer (score 0):

Change your comparison to first compare for `mrs`:

```
    if (name.startsWith(mrs)) {
        System.out.println("Hello,ma'am");
    }else if (name.startsWith(ms)) {
        System.out.println("Hello,ma'am");
    }else if (name.startsWith(miss)) {
        System.out.println("Hello,ma'am");
    }else if (name.startsWith(mr)) {
        System.out.println("Hello,sir");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Hello," +name);
    }
```

Explanation:

In your solution, the program flow will enter the first `if` branch (ie, the branch where name starts with `mr`). Since `mrs` also starts with `mr`, you need to change the order of comparison to compare the `mrs` before `mr`

Answer (score 0):

Try to swap the 'mr' and 'mrs' if else

```
if (name.startsWith(mrs)) {
    System.out.println("Hello,ma'am");
} else if (name.startsWith(mr)) {
    System.out.println("Hello,sir");
}else ......
```